# htaccess redirection causes session loss (Cake PHP)

Tags: php, .htaccess, session

My website is working fully in my local machine and quality server. However, having moved it to production, there is an issue: after the login the session is lost when I open another tab of the same website.

The setup: What is different about the production setup is that the site is inside a folder (domain/Folder), and the request for http://domain is redirecting to domain/folder on htaccess, so users don't see it on the browser address.

That works fine for the site in general, but after logging in the user, it all works while I stay withing http://domain/Folder, but whenever I open another browser tab with just http://domain, the session is completely lost / replaced / cleared.

I am guessing if the website got moved to the root folder it all would workout, but the root is otherwise occupied. Any ideas for a workaround?

(I am sorry for the confusing layout, it's not my area of expertise. Thank you in advance!)

Here is my relevant htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/Folder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Folder/$1 [L]
```